# How to Create Daily email Alert of Sentinel Cost

Tags: azure-sentinel

How to create daily alert on email id for sentinel cost?

Comment: we want to get alert daily on email of sentinel cost if u have any URl so u can share

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create alert Azure monitor to send daily usage of Sentinel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72909858/how-to-create-alert-azure-monitor-to-send-daily-usage-of-sentinel)

Answer (score 0):

You can create alerts in Sentinel in either of the following ways:

1. Associate the Create alerts action to a correlation rule. Sentinel generates an alert when the correlation rule fires.
2. Create alerts by using the REST API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).