# How to create alert Azure monitor to send daily usage of Sentinel

Tags: azure, sentiment-analysis, azure-sentinel

How to Create Alert  Azure monitor to send daily usage of Sentinel.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/daily-cap):

> When the daily cap is reached for a Log Analytics workspace, a banner is displayed in the Azure portal, and an event is written to the Operations table in the workspace. You should create an alert rule to proactively notify you when this occurs.

> When the daily cap is reached, you can receive an alert by creating a [log alert rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-unified-log) by specifying the **target scope** and **conditions**.

To view the effect of the daily cap, try following Kusto query, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/daily-cap#view-the-effect-of-the-daily-cap):

```
let DailyCapResetHour=14;
Usage
| where DataType !in ("SecurityAlert", "SecurityBaseline", "SecurityBaselineSummary", "SecurityDetection", "SecurityEvent", "WindowsFirewall", "MaliciousIPCommunication", "LinuxAuditLog", "SysmonEvent", "ProtectionStatus", "WindowsEvent")
| where TimeGenerated > ago(32d)
| extend StartTime=datetime_add("hour",-1*DailyCapResetHour,StartTime)
| where StartTime > startofday(ago(31d))
| where IsBillable
| summarize IngestedGbBetweenDailyCapResets=sum(Quantity)/1000. by day=bin(StartTime , 1d) // Quantity in units of MB
| render areachart
```

References: [Daily quota for Sentinel](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel/daily-quota-for-sentinel/m-p/3128882), [Ingestion Cost Spike detection Playbook](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/ingestion-cost-spike-detection-playbook/ba-p/2591301) and [How to analyze Microsoft Sentinel Daily Cap Alerts](https://www.verboon.info/2022/05/how-to-analyze-microsoft-sentinel-daily-cap-alerts-aadnoninteractiveusersigninlogs/)